# Is there a particular way to capture function errors in Saxon 9.9EE?

Tags: java, saxon

We are having an issue with Saxon since upgrading from 9.1HE to 9.9EE where function errors in our transform from Java silently stop processing and return the partially-generated xml, which causes issues in the next step of our transformations. We are setting our ErrorListener on the processor, the controller, the compiler and the transformer. Is there a different place to set this?

Comment: Functions written in XSLT? Or functions written in Java?

Comment: Standard XSLT functions like format-date or normalize-space.

Comment: Where are you upgrading from? 9.1 HE did not exist I think, the split between HE, PE and EE was done with the 9.2 release I think. So either 9.1 Saxon-B or a different version it is a HE release.

Comment: Sorry about that, I couldn't find the 9.1 versions listing easily. We used the free version of 9.1 for a long time and then recently upgraded to 9.9 EE.

Comment: I don't recognize the problem from your description; you'll need to supply more information about exactly what you are doing and exactly how it fails. For this kind of problem it may be more effective to raise an issue at saxonica.plan.io where we can follow up more interactively than is possible on StackOverflow. (`normalize-space` is an odd one: that doesn't have any failure conditions that I'm aware of, other than failures in computing its arguments).

Comment: Let me see if I can produce a minimal example to post there. Thanks!